# Question about the total probability law

Tags: probability, statistics, logic

[image]

- Why does $A= (A \cup B) +(A\cup C)$ and not $(A \cap B)+(A \cap C)$? Wouldn't you have to take the intersection to have elements of just $A$ instead of having the elements that $A$ overlaps with?
- Why is the total probability rule of this diagram $Pr(A)=Pr(b)\times Pr(A|B)+Pr(C)\times Pr(A|C)$? Why does $A$ depend on $B,$ $(A|B)$, and $C$, $(A|C)$? Is it because it's a subset of those universes?

thanks.

Comment: "and" precisely means $\cap$.

Comment: "A and B" is to be read as $A \cap B$, *not*, $A \cup B$.

Comment: Also, by definition, $P(A | B ) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $\cup$, not $+$, for set unions. The result why $A$ doesn't necessarily equal the latter union is because it may be the case that $A \setminus (B \cup C) \neq \emptyset$. If it happens to be the case also that $A \subseteq B \cup C$ then the latter union in your question *does* equal $A$. But not in general.